# Data Node not started

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins, hadoopy

[image]

I configured hadoop setting in my box and worked with example programs everything went fine and worked well all the Daemons also is in the running state. On the next day morning Data node not running.

Comment: Could you check the datanode log and post the latest lines here? Normally you can find the log under `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/`.

Comment: start-dfs.sh? Why do you think that data node is not running?

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the hadoop and also format the namenode . 
Generally the issue resolves on restarting the hadoop

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the following way:

1.By writing "localhost" in the file "hostname" which is located at /etc. And restart once it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

stop all services.
Add hostname to conf/slaves and run start-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem ... i resolved it by changing the  field in hdfs-site.xml ...... earlier my  field had the value ...${user.home}/hadoop/data/datanode
I changed it to $/hadoop/data/datanode and the datanode started